# How do I get the Left & Top property values of a Silverlight Canvas child

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Canvas with 2 children - an Image and a Rectangle.

I can get the height of the Rectangle as follows:

```
rectangle.Height
```

I can also get the height of the Rectangle like this:

```
inkCanvas1.Children[1].GetValue(Canvas.HeightProperty)
```

but when I try and get the Left (or Top) property of the Rectangle like this:

```
inkCanvas1.Children[1].GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)
```

it just returns zero.

I have also tried this:

```
Canvas.GetLeft(inkCanvas1.Children[1])
```

and that returns zero as well.

What I am certain of is that the Left and Top properties of the Rectangle are not zero (not least because I can see the Rectangle and move it around).

Solution anyone?

Comment: You have code in your application that is setting these properties and not for example using a Translate transform to give the appearance of moving this objects about?  Can you show the code that does this?

Comment: I've come to realise that it would seem these properties are only set when they are explicitly set.  For example, I had set the width and height properties but not the top and left.  However, if I explicitly set the top and left properties I can then retrieve them using the methods above.  I find this behaviour rather odd because the fact that the rectangle is at a location on the canvas means that his information must be stored somewhere even if not explicitly set.

Comment: Yes, there is a translate transform involved in locating the rectangle and I am now setting the top and left properties using the mouse coordinates used to draw the rectangle after it has been drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd resuscitate this question because I am now having similar difficulties.  If I add an image to my canvas and set the stretch property to uniform it also automatically centers the image.  Now if I draw a rectangle on the image and descale it to get the ROI from the underlying bitmap, I get the wrong region.  This is because the image is centered and my code is assuming the top left point of the image is 0,0.  The difficulty is that I cannot get the actual top-left point of my image because the code above just returns 0,0.  Neither can I seem to find a way to force the image to sit at the top-left position 0,0 in order that my code works.  I find it frustrating that anything can sit at a position on a canvas but there is no way of retireving that position.  Does anyone have any solutions to this?